# Looking to combine team placements and player transfers on the same graph

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

[teams, tournies, players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMAr9.png)

I am looking to combine team placements and players transfers on the same graph. X-axis will likely be time. I mocked up a poor example in ppt. I have tried sankey diagrams for the player transfers, but I cannot control the placement of the teams with respect to a timeline (most sankey options like in networkD3 do auto placement). I can do bump charts for the team placements. How would I combine both, and control the timeline so that they are synchronized? I have done both the sankey diagrams and bump charts in R and would prefer to do it there.

```
#placements    
#tourney  team  rank
1  1  1
1  2  2
1  3  3
1  4  4
2  1  1
2  2  3
2  3  2
2  4  4
3  1  2
3  2  1
3  3  4
3  4  3

#rosters    
#tourney  team  player
1  1  A
1  1  B
1  1  C
1  2  D
1  2  E
1  2  F
1  3  G
1  3  H
1  3  I
1  4  J
1  4  K
1  4  L
2  1  A
2  1  B
2  1  C
2  2  D
2  2  E
2  2  F
2  3  L
2  3  H
2  3  I
2  4  J
2  4  K
2  4  G
3  1  A
3  1  B
3  1  D
3  2  C
3  2  E
3  2  F
3  3  L
3  3  H
3  3  I
3  4  J
3  4  K
3  4  G
```

Comment: Added to the original a list of tournament placements and rosters.

Answer (score 0):

If you could include some data sources to pull that would be great, once those are available I would check-out some resources for making a [Sankey diagram in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/generating-sankey-diagrams-from-rcharts/)